# cypress 9.7.0 installation hangs at (Installing cypress 9.7.0)

Tags: cypress

initially installed through `npm install`, when trying to open cypress it is showing No version of Cypress is installed in: `C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.7.0\Cypress`

after that tried `./node_modules/.bin/cypress install`, then it is showing
Installing Cypress (version: 9.7.0)

Cypress 9.7.0 installation hangs,

node version used: v16.15.0

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try below:

```
npm install cypress --save-dev

npm audit --force

npm i
```

Comment: `npm audit --force` is quite a bad thing to do and it will not solve the issue of an installation hanging. It is more likely to get you into other compatibility issues!